# Compare 2 data sets in 2 worksheets and highlight the difference based on matched criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 data sets in 2 different worksheets and I'm trying to find out which account/s that have a different Yes/No to the main data source based on matching customer number and bucket.
For instance: assuming the table starts from cell A1 , so I need to highlight the cells: C7,C13,C14 and C15 because the same matching customer number and buckets in table B are Yes.

Is there away to achieve this, please?

Thank you

**Table A**

| Customer Number | Buckets | Yes/No |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 55850 | 1-30 | Yes |
| 55850 | 30-60 | Yes |
| 55850 | 60-90 | Yes |
| 55850 | 90-120 | Yes |
| 55850 | 120-180 | Yes |
| 32336 | 30-60 | No |
| 32336 | 60-90 | Yes |
| 30131 | 1-30 | Yes |
| 30131 | 30-60 | Yes |
| 30131 | 60-120 | Yes |
| 13914 | 1-30 | Yes |
| 13914 | 30-60 | No |
| 13914 | 60-90 | No |
| 13914 | 90-120 | No |

**Table B**

| Customer Number | Buckets | Yes/No |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13914 | 1-30 | Yes |
| 13914 | 30-60 | Yes |
| 13914 | 60-90 | Yes |
| 13914 | 90-120 | Yes |
| 30131 | 1-30 | Yes |
| 30131 | 30-60 | Yes |
| 30131 | 60-120 | Yes |
| 32336 | 30-60 | Yes |
| 32336 | 60-90 | Yes |
| 55850 | 1-30 | Yes |
| 55850 | 30-60 | Yes |
| 55850 | 60-90 | Yes |
| 55850 | 90-120 | Yes |
| 55850 | 120-180 | Yes |
| 55851 | 120-181 | Yes |
| 55852 | 120-182 | Yes |
| 55853 | 120-183 | Yes |
| 55854 | 120-184 | Yes |
| 55855 | 120-185 | Yes |
| 55856 | 120-186 | Yes |
| 55857 | 120-187 | Yes |
| 55858 | 120-188 | Yes |
| 55859 | 120-189 | Yes |
| 55860 | 120-190 | Yes |
| 55861 | 120-191 | Yes |
| 55862 | 120-192 | Yes |
| 55863 | 120-193 | Yes |
| 55864 | 120-194 | Yes |
| 55865 | 120-195 | Yes |
| 55866 | 120-196 | Yes |
| 55867 | 120-197 | Yes |

Comment: I would look at using index() with match()  with a simple compare

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks for that but the actual data is quite large and using the index/match takes long time. I wanted to get it efficiently by using array and reserve the values from table A and then loop in table B to compare with the data preserves from table A, but couldn’t get that right. Specially with joining the 3 columns of table A and start compare with split columns in table B.

Comment: So, show what you attempted and people may help improve it.

Comment: *so I need to highlight the cells* - in which table A, B or both.

Comment: in table A only. Table B is the data source to compare with.

Comment: You could just use conditional formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [Dictionary object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object), join columns A and B to create the unique key.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub compareAB()
    Dim arB, cel As Range, i As Long
    Dim dict As Object, k As String, n As Long
    Dim t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' read table B into dictionary
    arB = Range("Table B").Value2
    For i = 1 To UBound(arB)
        k = arB(i, 1) & ";" & arB(i, 2)
        If dict.exists(k) Then
            MsgBox "Duplicate key " & k & " on row " & i, vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf Len(k) > 1 Then
            dict.Add k, arB(i, 3)
        End If
    Next
    'Dim ky: For Each ky In dict.keys: Debug.Print ky, dict(ky): Next
 
    ' highlight diff in Table A
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Range("Table A").Columns(3)
        .Interior.Pattern = xlNone
        For Each cel In .Cells
            k = cel.Offset(, -2).Value2 & ";" & cel.Offset(, -1).Value2
            
            If dict.exists(k) Then
                If dict(k) <> cel.Value2 Then
                    cel.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) ' yellow
                    n = n + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox n & " rows highlighted in Table A", _
           vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")

End Sub
```